# Link two classes together by variables

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, attributes

I am learning python from a couple different books but mainly from learn python the hard way.

I am trying to better understand classes and ran into an example like :

```
class Dog(object):
     def __init__(self, name):
          self.name = name
          self.legs = 4
          self.carry_weight = 0

class Person(object):

     def __init__(self,name):
          self.name = name
          self.pet = None
          self.weight = 0


rover = Dog("Rover")
rover.carry_weight = 180
frank.pet = rover
print frank.name
print frank.pet.legs

if frank.weight < frank.pet.carry_weight:
print "Yes, Frank can ride his dog %s around the neighborhood" % frank.pet.name
```

So I learned that I can link the two instances of the class together and call attributes from one just by the other.  But I wanted to add an attribute

```
owner = None
```

Under Dog. And when I link Frank to rover it also links rover back to frank as its owner so even if i only know about rover i can pull up frank.

What I have come up with is this idea:

```
def assign_pet(self, petsname):
     self.pet = petsname
     petsname.owner = self.name
```

This seems to work fine but I wanted to know if this is the best way to go about this.  Is there a better way?

I don't know anyone that programs and so I don't have anywhere to go with questions.  Also I really tried to search for this answer but I feel like one of the three blind men feeling an elephant,  one moment Im googling "Whats a rope like thing that hangs about 7 feet off the ground" and the next I'm googling "whats this tree trunk that stomped on my face".  I hope you guys understood my joke.  Its hard to search for what you can't even describe properly.

Comment: This is exactly how I'd implement this.

Comment: (A person can own *many* pets; a pet *usually* only has one "owner".)

Comment: in which case, define `self.pets` as an empty `list` not a `None` and do in `assign_pet`: `self.pets.append(petsname); petsname.owner = self.name`

Comment: also I'm a fan of defining `__str__` for all my classes to be something user-friendly, then simply adding the object to things not the user-friendly name of it. e.g. define `Dog.__str__ = lambda self: self.name` and do `self.pets.append(pet)` instead of the pet's name :)